# In Lua, how to insert numbers as 32 bits to front of a binary sequence？

Tags: nginx, lua, luajit, openresty

I'm new to `Lua` when I began to use `OpenResty`, I want to output a image and it's x,y coordinate together as one binary sequence to the clients, looks like: `x_int32_bits y_int32_bits image_raw_data`. At the client, I know the first 32 bits is x, the second 32 is y, and the others are image raw data. I met some questions:

1. How to convert number to 32 binary bits in Lua?
2. How to merge two 32 bits to one 64 bits sequence?
3. How to insert 64 bits to front of image raw data? And how to be fastest?
4. file:read("*a") got string type result, is the result ASCII sequence or like "000001110000001..." string?

What I'm thinking is like below, I don't know how to convert 32bits to string format same as file:read("*a") result.

@EgorSkriptunoff thank you, you opened a window for me. I wrote some new code, would you take a look, and I have another question, is the string merge method `..` inefficient and expensive? Specially when one of the string is very large. Is there an alternative way to merge the bytes string?

**NEW CODE UNDER @EgorSkriptunoff 's GUIDANCE**

```
function _M.number_to_int32_bytes(num)
    return ffi.string(ffi.new("int32_t[1]", num), 4)
end


local x, y = unpack(v)

local file, err = io.open(image_path, "rb")

if nil ~= file then
    local image_raw_data = file:read("*a")
    if nil == image_raw_data then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "read file error:", err)
    else
        -- Is the .. method inefficient and expensive? Because the image raw data maybe large, 
        -- so will .. copy all the data to a new string? Is there an alternative way to merge the bytes string?
        output = utils.number_to_int32_bytes(x) .. utils.number_to_int32_bytes(y) .. image_raw_data 

        ngx.print(output)
        ngx.flush(true)
    end

    file:close()
end
```

**OLD CODE:**

```
function table_merge(t1, t2)
   for k,v in ipairs(t2) do
      table.insert(t1, v)
   end 

   return t1
end

function numToBits(num, bits)
    -- returns a table of bits
    local t={} -- will contain the bits
    for b=bits,1,-1 do
        rest=math.fmod(num,2)
        t[b]=rest
        num=(num-rest)/2
    end
    if num==0 then return t else return {'Not enough bits to represent this number'} end
end


-- Need to insert x,y as 32bits respectively to front of image binary sequence
function output()
    local x = 1, y = 3
    local file, err = io.open("/storage/images/1.png", "rb")

    if nil ~= file then
        local d = file:read("*a") ------- type(d) is string, why?
        if nil == d then
            ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "read file error:", err)
        else
            -- WHAT WAY I'M THINKING -----------------

            -- Convert x, y to binary table, then merge them to one binary table
            data = table_merge(numToBits(x, 32), numToBits(y, 32))

            -- Convert data from binary table to string
            data = convert_binary_table_to_string(data) -- HOW TO DO THAT? --------

            -- Insert x,y data to front of image data, is data .. d ineffective？
            data = data .. d

            -------------------------------------------

            ngx.print(data)
            ngx.flush(true)
        end

        file:close()
    end
end
```

Comment: To convert Lua number `x` to 4-byte binary string `x_32_bits = ffi.string(ffi.new("uint32_t[1]", x), 4)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, thank you very much, I have updated some new code, and  a new question to the post, would you take a look, thank you!

Comment: Just don't concat, pass all strings as parameters ngx.print(str1, str2, str3) And yes concatenation may be expensive (Lua does string interning)

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler Thank you!